# When will PayPal Credit be accepted in PayPal Adaptive Payment Method

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

PayPal Credit is the very important feature now becoming widely used by most of the PayPal users. It is really an issue that this couldn't be facilitated if the store servers PayPal Adaptive Payment Method.

Can we expect this feature (PayPal Credit) will work anyway soon in Adaptive Method.
Can PayPal experts confirms?

Thank you in Advance